# MySQL foreign key error

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, errors

I need to update rows in a `child table`,but I am getting following error while I run the code,

**Company Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `company` 
(
 `Company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Company_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `BuildingNameNumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Street_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Area` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Landmark` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `PIN_code` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `PhoneMobile_number` char(15) NOT NULL,
 `Website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Fax` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Upload_logo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tin_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `CreatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `CreatedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `UpdatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `UpdatedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_active` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`Company_id`),
);
```

**Service Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `service` (
`service_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serial_number` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `tax` float(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `is_active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`service_id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `service_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`Company_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

When I trying to update the service table I am getting error as

```
**Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`etailershop`.`service`, CONSTRAINT `service_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`Company_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)  0.031 sec**
```

I was trying to find the error, I do understand the foreign key constraint but I could not find what is wrong with this, similar structure and constraint tables are working fine.

Comment: Please post your update query.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you're trying to update a row to `service` table that does not have a valid value for the `company_id` field based on the values currently stored in `company` table.

If you post some more code someone can help you diagnose the specific cause.

Comment: Yes, it seems like that only, but the company_id value is present in the company table, confusing..

Comment: The update query is UPDATE service SET company_id = '183' AND service_name = 'Story Books' AND price ='400.00' WHERE service_id = '9' LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my case, I used "AND" in my update query, I removed the "AND" operator, it is now working fine, the update statement and solved update statements are given below,

**Update statement**

> UPDATE service SET company_id = '183' AND service_name = 'Story Books'
>   AND price ='400.00' WHERE service_id = '9' LIMIT 1

**Update Statement [SOLVED]**

> UPDATE service  SET  company_id = 187,   service_name = 'Test Books',
>   price = 500.00  WHERE  service_id = 7

Small changes but working fine now.

Comment: You didn't just remove the `AND`, you replaced them with commas `,`

Comment: Yes, somehow, it is solved.